How to force GitHub to update a PR merge branch?
Dependabot sent us a PR that bumped a bunch of NPM dependency versions, and the package-lock.json file in that PR was incorrect, causing npm ci to fail. Unfortunately, we merged this PR before we realised this.
We noticed the issue and created two PRs to fix it:

One reverted the bad Dependabot PR.
One modified our CI workflow action to use npm ci instead of npm install, so that we would notice if any future PR updated package.json without updating package-lock.json to match.

At some point during this time Dependabot sent us some more PRs that are not defective.
I have a PR that I can check via gh pr checkout <NNNN>, and when I subsequently run tests in the PR branch they pass. I can also merge that branch into the target branch locally, using git merge <PR_BRANCH> (or with --squash), and the combination of target branch + PR branch also passes tests.
However, when GitHub runs the tests for this PR the tests fail. This seems to be because our workflow uses the checkout action to obtain the code to test, checking out PR merge branch refs/pull/PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER/merge, and apparently this merge branch is defective, possibly because the target branch was defective at the time the PR was created.
How do I get GitHub to update the PR merge branch, so that it is up-to-date with respect to the (now fixed) target branch?

Neither @dependabot rebase and @dependabot recreate fixed the issue. [EDIT: I now believe I was mistaken about this.]

The GitHub docs mention an "update branch" button, but it appears that this button is for updating the PR branch (by merge or rebase from the target branch), not updating the PR merge branch.



What parameter for checkout do you use, specifically for ref?

Can you not just edit the PR and change the base branch?

In this kind of situation, I checkout the PR branch locally, rebase it manually and force push it back up. That will update the merge branch and trigger all the workflows again from this fixed state.

@BenjaminW.: Our workflow .yml just invokes uses: actions/checkout@v4 with: persist-credentials: false; looks like that is doing /usr/bin/git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/pull/8248/merge

@joanis: It's not clear why my doing the rebase will succeed where @dependabot rebase and @dependabot recreate have not, but I suppose it's worth a try.

OK, I had two different PRs exhibiting seemingly the same behaviour, but I think that (per @joanis's suggestion) that @dependabot rebase may very well have been enough to fix the problem (and if not then @dependabot recreate certainly was), but both PRs subsequently failed CI due to other problems (in one case npm ci fails due to a legit version conflict, and in the other an unrelated test failure) and I failed to notice this.
